# Date and Time Difference between 2 timestamps?

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to know how to get the date and time difference in minutes based on 
which i need to do expiry of 1 hour for login , after 60 minutes has expired users can resume  login .

```
$currentdate = 1336468008 
$storeddate = 1336464866
```

Comment: First grade mathematics?

Comment: First grade mathematics? The question is not how, is the tool to do the task.

Comment: Actually, @YagoRiveiro, the question is _exactly_ "how to get the date and time difference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$timeDiff = $currentdate - $storeddate
```

Gives you difference in seconds

Divide by 60 for minutes and by 60 again for hours.

You could just divide the result by 3600 and if the answer > 1 set expired.

```
if(($currentdate - $storeddate)/3600 > 1) doExpiryStuff();
```

Comment: then you're doing something wrong

Comment: so sorry ... am new to php so i hav no idea... thanks a lot was trying somethin like  strtotime($currentdate ) - strtotime($storeddate )

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime::diff` and the `DateInterval` class can format to bring you precicely what you need, i.e. total minutes.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: I think that that's an overkill. `if(($now - $then) > (60 * 60))` would do the trick

Comment: how to accept ?? , well 1 more question comin in  :)

Comment: @Sparkle Click the little grey 'tick'/'check mark' next to the question you believe is the correct answer, or which worked for you case.